# Localhost Google Endpoints API blocked

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

Hum I'm using Google Cloud Endpoints.  Worked fine yesterday.  However today (10/10/2013) when I run the localhost API explorer (on any of my apps), I'm unable to load the API explorer.

For example if I go to:

```
http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer
```

Nothing loads and if I right click, go to Inspect Element, console area I see a warning (that I actually suspect is unrelated, regardless it's only a warning) here is that warning....

```
[blocked] The page at https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A11080%2F_ah%2Fapi#p/ ran insecure content from http://localhost:11080/_ah/api/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-…IRCTlEug#parent=https%3A%2F%2Fapis-explorer.appspot.com&rpctoken=791277094.?base=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A11080%2F_ah%2Fapi:1
```

Thoughts?  Using the API explorer still works on deployed apps.  There are warnings on deloyed app too insecure images, but the API explorer there works.  Comically I'm teaching this topic in a college course tomorrow. :)  Just curious if a new security rule got put in place  recently on Chrome.  Or an endpoints change that brought down the localhost API explorer.

Thanks for any help on localhost API exploring. :)

Answer (score 3):

It appears you can just change the https to http in the redirect page and it will load again.